# Converting Char to Bytes, Strings to Bytes in Java

Tags: java

I have been working on using sockets to send data and the data sent is an ASCII protocol with a message structure. The structure of the message is in this link https://imgur.com/a/odVQk5X. This is the code I worked out so far.

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out.write(byte_array); //Send data to the socket
out.flush();

String reply = in.readLine(); //Read for any response returned by the server
System.out.println("Reply from Server: " + reply);
```

My question is if there is an alternative to instead of converting Char to Bytes before sending to String to Bytes before sending. This is the current codes for the conversion before sending it to the socket.

```
byte[] byte_array = new byte[] {7, charToByte('0'), charToByte('5'), charToByte('N'), charToByte('R'), charToByte('X'), 13};
public static byte charToByte(char a)
{
    return (byte)(a & 0xFF);
}
```

So Basically what I want to know if there is way to convert a String "\a01NIP\r" to bytes because I have tried `getBytes()` but the result I get is "Reply from Server: null".

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Character.toString((char) 7) + "01NIP\r").getBytes("UTF-8")));`

Comment: Did you try `new byte[] {7, '0', '5', 'N', 'R', 'X', 13}`? Also, what's your default encoding?

Comment: [link] https://imgur.com/a/WqJyNVO updated on the message structure link